# GLM on Proportion Response and Categorical Predictor gives strange standard errors

Tags: generalized-linear-model, proportion, quasi-binomial

I am looking at the effects of seawater salinity levels on fertilization rates. Salinity levels are set so they are treated as factors.

```
   Call:
    glm(formula = cbind(fertilized, unfertilized) ~ salinity, 
    family = "quasibinomial", data = fert.sal)

    Deviance Residuals: 
        Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
    -5.2459  -0.3600  -0.0002   1.0971   4.9201  

    Coefficients:
                Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
    (Intercept)   -22.31    1929.46  -0.012    0.991
    salinity20     17.96    1929.46   0.009    0.993
    salinity25     23.26    1929.46   0.012    0.990
    salinity30     24.36    1929.46   0.013    0.990
    salinity33     27.42    1929.46   0.014    0.989

    (Dispersion parameter for quasibinomial family taken to be 3.102026)

    Null deviance: 7450.93  on 74  degrees of freedom
    Residual deviance:  222.59  on 70  degrees of freedom
    AIC: NA

    Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 17
```

When viewed graphically, differences in fertilization rates between salinity levels are quite obvious (as also shown by estimates); however, standard errors are strangely all similar and P-values non-significant. Everyone is welcome to point out where errors might be.  Thanks